# How to detect if Siri button is clicked from Apple TV Siri Remote

Tags: tvos, siri-remote

I am clicking on Siri button of Apple TV Siri Remote.
Now, I want Siri to perform action by saying on click of Siri Button of remote within my App.
Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

No.

Unfortunately, there is no way to detect if the siri button has been clicked.

Clicking the siri button will send your app in background giving the siri process the focus.

I would recommend filling a feature request using their [bug report system](https://bugreport.apple.com/)